# Resetting a DateTime-field with invalid data, programmatically

Tags: c#-4.0, dynamics-crm, dynamics-365

In Dynamics CRM 365:

I'm coding a plugin for a workflow, that's supposed to set a DateTime-field to a given date. The code works fine, unless the field **ALREADY** contains the value **'31-12-9999'**.

Every time I try to Update the entity's field with a new DateTime-value I get the following error:

```
The date-time format for 9999-12-31T23:59:59-00:00 is invalid, or value is outside the supported range.
```

The format isn't a problem, seeing as it works fine with any other date. I know for a fact the problem is because of the 31-12-9999 in UTC. 
As soon as I try to access the field, it tries to convert it to GMT+2 (local timezone) and fails.

---

**The question:**

Is there a way to force delete/update the value in a field through a coded plugin?

---

I have tried with the normal organizationservice CRUD-operations but none of them work.

Comment: I don't really understand the question. The highest possible value is `30-12-9999` but the problem is you're trying to assign `31-12-9999`?

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve (beyond setting a DateTime field with invalid data)?

Comment: As I wrote, the highest manually entered value is 30-12-9999, however if you assign a value to the field through a plugin (code) you can assign 31-12-9999. Doing this will distrupt future actions on this field, because you retrieve a UTC-value that's already maxed, and say you convert it to GMT+2 (my zone) you'll get an invalid date.

Comment: Actually, it's not really relevant either. I'll rewrite the question :)

Comment: The invalid date is being set by an automatic process to indicate either infinity or 'don't start yet' . I realize that we have to go fix that process, but it would be nice, if I could clear the invalid field in all of our records. I guess we'll have to do that through the database.

Comment: Perhaps try setting your own timezone in CRM to UTC or even better UTC -5:00 to see if that prevents the error.

Comment: Was this resolved?

Comment: In regards to the original question, no, I never found out if that was possible, so I assume no. It had nothing to do with format, but the invalid value yielded by a conversion from UTC to GMT+1. All programmatic access / manipulation of the invalid DateTime-fields would yield the error and stop the execution of the plugin.

Comment: We used a value well below maxium allowed DateTime-value, so when retrieving the DateTime, the conversion to our timezone would not be out of range. 
Aron's solution would probably have worked, but I only code the plugins, and the administrator of our CRM would not change the timezones.

Answer (score 0):

This should help or give ideas

https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/237525

"the date format used for those fetch conditions has to match the date format configured for that user in CRM"